# Importing dict-like data into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a number of data files written in a dict-like format:

```
{"score": [0.9995803236961365, 0.00041968212462961674], "key": "Am2mVTMbhd0y", "label": "0"}
{"score": [0.9997120499610901, 0.00028794570243917406], "key": "AmG8StB8hM2k", "label": "0"}
{"score": [0.8841496109962463, 0.11585044860839844], "key": "Alt137zv2nY6", "label": "0"}
{"score": [0.9999467134475708, 5.334055458661169e-05], "key": "AmGdF7cY4X22", "label": "0"}
```

What I'd like to do is import them into pandas, with the columns as 'key', 'label' and 'score' - and to have to have the two numerical values in separate columns. I've tried importing the file as a dict, but I get:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: this error occour because your file might contain some error which is not as per dictionary formating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need parameter `lines=True` in [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html):

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines=True)
print (df)
            key  label                                         score
0  Am2mVTMbhd0y      0   [0.999580323696136, 0.00041968212462900004]
1  AmG8StB8hM2k      0  [0.9997120499610901, 0.00028794570243900004]
2  Alt137zv2nY6      0     [0.8841496109962461, 0.11585044860839801]
3  AmGdF7cY4X22      0    [0.99994671344757, 5.3340554586611695e-05]

print (type(df['score'].iat[0]))
<class 'list'>
```

For convert `lists` to columns use `DataFrame` constructor with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('score', 1),
                pd.DataFrame(df['score'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('score')], axis=1)
print (df)
            key  label    score0    score1
0  Am2mVTMbhd0y      0  0.999580  0.000420
1  AmG8StB8hM2k      0  0.999712  0.000288
2  Alt137zv2nY6      0  0.884150  0.115850
3  AmGdF7cY4X22      0  0.999947  0.000053
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#add your data in a list
data = [{"score": [0.9995803236961365, 0.00041968212462961674], "key": "Am2mVTMbhd0y", "label": "0"},
{"score": [0.9997120499610901, 0.00028794570243917406], "key": "AmG8StB8hM2k", "label": "0"},
{"score": [0.8841496109962463, 0.11585044860839844], "key": "Alt137zv2nY6", "label": "0"},
{"score": [0.9999467134475708, 5.334055458661169e-05], "key": "AmGdF7cY4X22", "label": "0"}]
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```